# Why I'm getting 'setRoutingData is not a function' in Symfony 4 WebPack?

Tags: symfony, webpack, symfony4

My app.js code is following

```
import Routing from '../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/js/router'
import Routes from './routes.json'
//import routes from '../../web/js/fos_js_routes.js'

  Routing.setRoutingData(Routes);
```

And I'm getting following error..

```
TypeError: _vendor_friendsofsymfony_jsrouting_bundle_Resources_js_router__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.setRoutingData is not a function
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
const routes = require('../../public/js/routes.json');
import Routing from '../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.min.js';

Routing.setRoutingData(routes);
```

like the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html) suggests.

Beware that you should use `jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.min.js` and not `jsrouting-bundle/Resources/js/router.js`.

You probably forget the public folder in your path.

Comment: Could you open the vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.min.js file to see what it contains?

Comment: It contains !function(e,t){var n=t();"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?........ etc

Comment: could you use console.log(routes) to see if it's a valid object?

Comment: Object { base_url: "", routes: {…}, prefix: "", host: "localhost", port: "", scheme: "http" }

Comment: very odd, I use it exactly like this. console.log(Routing); what do you get?

Comment: Also in which file do you include it? do you compile it through webpack?